# In the new Loot 2.0 system, when are a legendary item's stats determined?

Tags: diablo-iii

Blizz have made it so it's much more likely to get items which are relevant to your character.  Whilst overall great,  I'm now struggling to gear up my followers.

If I find a legendary shield with my wizard, identifying it will inevitably lead to a pointless shield full of int. However if I stash it and then ID it with my Barb, will it then have strength and be useful for the templar?

When are a legendary item's stats determined, when it drops, or when it is identified?

Comment: Unless I misread it, I think relevant items just don't have useless stats (Witch Doctor Weapon will no longer have strength, etc). Not that ALL items will only drop with class relevant stats. But Shields can still have strength because it still makes sense for it to be there. But maybe not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Item stats are determined upon drop. If you stash it and later identify it on a different class, it will still be specific to the class that it dropped on for you. If the item does have stats for a different class, those stats were still predetermined on the drop. This is because Loot 2.0 does not guarantee that all drops will be specific to your class, so although rare, there are possible exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

If it is to follow the current system, it will be determined upon drop. Quote from the wiki:

> Item stats are set the moment the item is generated, and are based on the monster or object that drops the item, the item level, and the character's Magic Find. How or when a player identifies an item has no effect on the stats or the quality of the roll, and any superstitions to the contrary are unfounded.

I could not find any solid info for 2.0, but from what I've at least heard the identify system will not change, just how relevant loot is towards the class you play and so on.

Edit: A bit more fumbling, there are *indications* that the identification system might even be removed in 2.0, or near future. Simple speculation, but if you ask me it makes sense as the system is kinda redundant anyway. Considering the 2.0 or RoS isn't even out yet, we need to just wait and see, things can still be changed.

Comment: Thanks - though I'll hold off on accepting your answer for a bit in case anyone has any concrete info for 2.0

Comment: 2.0 IS out and currently you only need to identify legendary items. That being said, I am sure stats are still rolled upon drop and not upon identification.

Comment: I'm not sure how Magic Find works into the equation as it definitely doesn't have weight like it used to. Magic Find no longer appears as a stat on items as of 2.0.

Comment: Magic find is still found on some gear (specifically, some legendaries, and of course still available from Topaz gems in helms).  Also, old gear that had magic find from pre-2.0 still has said magic find on it.  See [this thread](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11884258481) on the official Diablo 3 forums for more info about Magic Find in 2.0

Answer (score 2):

Determined on drop. Tested with 10+ legendary items - the most convincing was finding magefist with my Demon Hunter - had my Wizard ID it - came up with 378 Dex. All others had primary stats of character finding them as well.

Comment: Do you have any independently verifiable sources to confirm this?

Answer (score -3):

I tested this out today with an item ( the thunder belt)

However, I found it with my wizard and since it was the 2nd one I found I decided to try to ID it with my monk and BAM! It rolled Dex. So there you go, the stats are not predetermined on drop like they used to be.

Comment: Interesting, although I'd like a few more data points to confirm this.

Comment: I've had several pieces of gear rolled with Intelligence or Strength on my Monk.  Loot 2.0 does NOT guarantee a item rolled with your current character's primary stat; it just makes it more likely to.

Comment: One item is not an appropriate sample size.

Answer (score -3):

As Sharain said the item is generated when it's dropped by the mob and not when identified.

I can comfirm that the droprate on legendary items is 10%.
As it seems you only need 10% magic find to farm legendary items.

Source:
http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/8966397468#16

> MF will apply 100% of its benefit to Blue items, 30% to Yellow items,
>   and 10% to Legendary and Set items. This means someone with 300% MF
>   will end up finding roughly 30% more Legendary and Set items than
>   someone with 0%.

Comment: The stuff about magic find isn't very useful, since that's not at all what the question is asking about.  Other than that, your first sentence is what answers the question, and it's already been said.  Do you have anything else to add that hasn't already been stated?